# Django GenericRelation recursive import

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

I'm trying to create a system, for a User to worte a comment on an other User. So I create a models with `GenericRelation` like this:

*App1\models.py:*

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericRelation

from app2.models import Social

class User(AbstractUser):
    """
    Default User model used for authentification system
    """

    relation = GenericRelation(Social)    # recently added
```

*App2\models.py:*

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericForeignKey
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

from app1.models import User

class Social(models.Model):
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()

    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType,
                                     on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    author= models.ForeignKey(User,  # Member who wrote the message
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                             related_name='wrote')
    message= models.TextField()
```

Before adding the field `relation` in `User`. I don't have any problem but I was remake the work of `GenericRelation` and I want to simplify my cod.

Then the problem appear when i run the server. I'm in a recursive import loop...

```
file .\app2\models.py
  from app2.models import Social
file .\app1\models.py
  from app1.models import User
```

Would there be a possibility of solving this problem by keeping a `GenericRelation` on Social and `GenericRelation` for my `User`?
Because after I want to add an other `GenericRelation(Social)` on an other model/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to reference `User` model as string in `ForeignKey`, like so:

```
author = models.ForeignKey(
    'app1.User',
    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    related_name='wrote')
)
```

And, also, remove `from app1.models import User`.

Comment: This is exactly, what I need. Does it have any risk to do that?

Comment: @Buky No, this is standard practice, to do so.